# Trying to give D3 treediagram css styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, d3.js

I am having a hard time giving my tree diagram style. Now when it renders it is just a fat unsymmetrical transition diagonal. I have tried adding `!important;` on the css class `.link` but it doesn't change anything. I have also tried adding `.style('fill', 'none', 'stroke', '#ccc', 'stroke-width', '2px')` directly on the links in the d3 code part but it still doesn't work. Someone with better knowledge that have any input on this? Thanks.

I attach a screenshot of the treediagram and the code bellow.

[Treediagram_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJlZj.png)

```
<template>
  <section id="plugin_tree-diagram">
      I am a tree!
  </section>
  <div id="svgcontainer">
    <button>roll</button>
    <span id="roll-value"></span>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none !important;
  stroke: #ccc !important;
  stroke-width: 2px !important;
}

</style>

<script  >
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import {
  select,
  line,
  scaleLinear,
  min,
  max,
  curveBasis,
  axisBottom,
  axisLeft,
  
} from "d3";
// import * as d3select from 'd3-selection';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'TreeDiagram',
  setup() {
    
    return {}
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
var treeData =
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "children": [
      { 
        "name": "Slag 1",
        "children": [
          { "name": "1" },
          { "name": "2" },
          { "name": "3" },
          { "name": "4" },
          { "name": "5" },
          { "name": "6" }
        ]
      },
      { "name": "Level 2: B" }
    ]
  };

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("#svgcontainer").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth. Hur långt diagrammet ska sträcka sig.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "red" : "#000";
      });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "red" : "#000";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; })
      .style('fill', 'none', 'stroke', '#ccc', 'stroke-width', '2px');

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      // .style('fill', 'none', 'stroke', '#ccc', 'stroke-width', '2px')
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  // Bug i denna funktion med diagonalen. 
  function diagonal(s, d) {

   const path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(event, d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }
}
    });
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: This looks odd: `.style('fill', 'none', 'stroke', '#ccc', 'stroke-width', '2px');` - did you try and remove it since you have `.attr("class", "link")` in `linkEnter`

Comment: Hi! Yes it was just there commented out. I tried giving it style with the d3 ```.style()``` directly. So that was done without giving it the class name link. And then also trying to give it style via a class name "link" in the ```<style scoped>```section

Comment: It's commented out in `linkEnter` but still present in `link`... ?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I replaced it in ```link``` with this instead ```.style({'fill': 'none', 'stroke': '#ccc', 'stroke-width': '2px'})```But then all my diagonal lines just disappear...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was the useage of `<style scoped>`
once I removed that it worked like intended.